B2 Visa Stay Duration Rules
We have a question about the rules regarding the duration of stay in the U.S. on a B2 tourist visa.
We arrived in the U.S. on September 3rd to visit our daughter and granddaughter and plan to stay until February 25th. Recently, we learned that our daughter is pregnant, with a due date of July 6th. We are planning to return to the U.S. around that time to assist her and stay for approximately five and a half months.
We understand that the maximum stay on a B2 visa is typically 180 days per entry. However, we’re unsure if there is a limit on the total number of days we can stay in the U.S. within a year, regardless of how many times we enter.
Our specific questions are:
1.  Is the maximum allowable stay on a B2 visa 180 days per entry, or is it capped at 180 days total within a 12-month period?
2.  For example, since we will have stayed for about two months in early 2025, would we be able to stay for a full 180 days during our next visit in July, or only for the remaining four months of the year?
We want to make sure we follow the rules while planning our trips and supporting our daughter and her newborn.
Thank you for your advice!

Welcome to TSE. How long were you [asdmitted for] on this trip? Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142508/what-is-the-minimum-wait-before-i-may-i-re-enter-the-usa-after-a-90-day-visit-on


We understand that the maximum stay on a B2 visa is typically 180 days per entry.

Officially it is "six months."  I have seen some images of passport stamps that imply an interpretation of six months as meaning 180 days, but I've also seen some that are truly six calendar months.  I don't know what the current policy is.

However, we’re unsure if there is a limit on the total number of days we can stay in the U.S. within a year, regardless of how many times we enter.

There isn't.  The regulations even allow for a B-class visitor to be admitted for up to one year as well as to extend their stay indefinitely in increments of up to six months, but in both cases it is of course necessary to establish that the person is a genuine visitor, and this of course becomes increasingly difficult the longer one seeks to stay.


Is the maximum allowable stay on a B2 visa 180 days per entry, or is it capped at 180 days total within a 12-month period?


Neither.  The maximum allowable stay is however long you've been admitted for, which you should be able to check at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov.  The regulations provide that a passport inspector must have approval from a supervisor to grant admission for a period shorter than six months.


For example, since we will have stayed for about two months in early 2025, would we be able to stay for a full 180 days during our next visit in July, or only for the remaining four months of the year?


In theory you can be admitted for six months, but it's also possible that the officer would grant a shorter period.  I think it unlikely, but I don't really know.  In any event, if the officer does grant a shorter period of admission, you can apply to extend your stay.  This is expensive, but would allow you to stay since these applications are generally processed rather slowly.
If you look online for information from Canadian retirees who have properties in the United States, you'll see that they generally seek to limit their presence in the US to no more than 182 days.  This is not because of immigration law but because of tax law.  You may want to look into the "substantial presence test," which is used to determine whether someone is a resident of the US as defined in the Internal Revenue Code.  There is a "closer connection" exception to this test, meaning a closer connection to a foreign country, but this exception is not available to someone who spends more than half of the year in the US.
If you qualify as a resident under the Internal Revenue Code, you are required to report your worldwide income and potentially pay income tax on it.  Whether you would actually owe anything depends of course on your specific circumstances, but you may want to investigate the tax implications of your planned visit.  Perhaps the cost would be modest and you would consider it justified, or perhaps not, but then you'll be able to plan your itinerary accordingly.
The "rule of thumb" you often read about -- mentioned in the other answer -- is more of a threshold for further scrutiny than anything else.  If you don't meet it (and as correctly noted in the other answer, you won't) you can expect more thorough questions about your intentions while in the US and the likelihood of your returning home.

the Canadians need to worry not only that the US would consider them a resident and demand taxes, but that their home province would consider them to NOT be a resident and no longer offer "free" healthcare (among other benefits.)

There is no explicit rule for how quickly you can return to the US after a previous trip, nor for the total time you can spent in the US across multiple trips.
However the immigration officials must believe that you are not attempting to live in the US.  There is a general rule of thumb for determining this that you must spend more time outside of the US than inside it - which is a bar you will not meet.  At the end of your trip, you will have spent around 11 months out of the preceding 15 months in the US which would normally be far too much to be considered not living in the US.  It is possible that an immigration official would make an exception due to the stated pregnancy, however I would not rely on this and I'd say there's a reasonable chance you will be denied entry.  If you were admitted, then upon departure you would likely need to stay outside of the US for at least 6 months before being allowed entry again.
If you are admitted for the 2nd trip, you also need to be aware that you will need to file a US tax return for (at least) 2025 as you will be deemed a US Resident under the "Substantial presence test".  Depending on your country of citizenship you may have to pay US tax on your worldwide income.
